# Table of tables HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I am making a webpage which will involve having 9 tables in a 3x3 formation on screen.

So far I have the 9 tables on top of each other, but I would like them set up kind of like a tic tac toe board in the centre of the screen, and I am going to fill them all differently. Any suggestion? I have given them all the same ID, and individual classes if that helps..

PS please don't suggest that I just make different cells - it is important that they are different tables!

html:

```
<table id='table' class="table1">
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table2">
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table3">
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table4">
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table5">
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table6">
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table7">
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table8">
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table9">
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
#table { 
    padding: 0px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    outline-color: red;
    outline-style: solid;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Stop using same ID and also use double quotes for consistency of code format.

Comment: You can't have duplicate ids, switch to a class instead

Comment: Can you explain _why_ they need to be tables and not cells in table? Because I'm trying to figure out what you are doing that needs that sort of layout.

Comment: You got IDs and classes mixed up. IDs should be unique and classes can be repeated.

Comment: thanks for the tip - switched to classes and fixed double quotes :) did this intermittently and forgot to check style..

Comment: You are only going to put tabular data in those tables, aren't you? Tables aren't for layout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html.

Comment: yes! data is going in the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap them in a div and have them like the following:

```css
.table {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-table;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline-color: red;
  outline-style: solid;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
div {
  width: 248px;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="table"><tr></tr></table>
  <table class="table"><tr></tr></table>
  <table class="table"><tr></tr></table>
  <table class="table"><tr></tr></table>
  <table class="table"><tr></tr></table>
  <table class="table"><tr></tr></table>
  <table class="table"><tr></tr></table>
  <table class="table"><tr></tr></table>
  <table class="table"><tr></tr></table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q1vcwppa/

Answer (score 0):

Here was the first way that came to mind using `width` and `float` attributes. Pretty sure you could also do something in flexbox to make it so that the tables stayed the same height but my biggest recommendation is that you *really* shouldn't need to do this, but without knowing more about this I can't particularly give you more reasons.

```css
table.table {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<table class='table' id="table1">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class='table' id="table2">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class='table' id="table3">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class='table' id="table4">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class='table' id="table5">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class='table' id="table6">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class='table' id="table7">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class='table' id="table8">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class='table' id="table9">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

OR TRY THIS !

```
 <div>
<table id='table' class="table1">
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table2">
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table3">
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table4">
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table5">
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table6">
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table7">
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table8">
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
<table id='table' class="table9">
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
</div>



div{
width:250px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#table { 
padding: 0px; 
margin: 0 auto;
outline-color: red;
outline-style: solid;
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
display:inline-block;
}
.table1{
background-color:blue;
}
 .table2{
background-color:green;
}
.table3{
background-color:orange;
```